# How do you sum the single max values of multiple groups?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, max

I have a data table which, among other things, contains a list of Values, each is assigned a Group ID.

I would like to sum the max value of each group.

I can do this easily by using a helper table (with MAXIFS) as can be seen below. However, for various reasons, I would like to avoid any helper columns/tables and produce the result from a single, non-CSE, formula.

[image]

How can this be done?

Comment: Not using array formulas would be tricky I think. A challenge for Scott...

Comment: Outside of dynamic array formula, like below, there is no way without CSE or vba.

Comment: @ScottCraner Not even a SUMPRODUCT solution? I thought all array formulas could be reformatted into a SUMPRODUCT? So far, I have `=SUMPRODUCT($B$3:$B$14*(B3:B14=MAXIFS(B3:B14,A3:A14,A3:A14)))` but my problem is removing the duplicate max values e.g. group 2 in my example. I am currently trying to sum them and divide by the count... but i'm having difficulty.

Comment: SUMPRODUCT would work if the GROUP was truly a number, but my assumption is that the numbers shown are just a representation and not the actual data.

Comment: @JvdV but I do not know if you can get a unique return from filterxml.

Comment: I take that back, SUMPRODUCT will not work either.  There is no way to get the unique list, that I know of, without CSE or VBA.

Comment: @ScottCraner please see my answer. It seems to work (even with text as the group ID) but I haven't fully tested it yet. Can you see any obvious problems/improvements that I may have missed?

Comment: Appears I was wrong, I am blaming it on the fact that I am just waking, yeah thats it, not enough caffeine.  Good job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also try this:

```
= SUMPRODUCT( 
 MAXIFS( $B$2:$B$14, $A$2:$A$14, $A$2:$A$14 )
 / COUNTIFS( $A$2:$A$14, $A$2:$A$14 ) )
```

**Explanation:** *(provided now as previously I was travelling).*

`MAXIFS`: Returns the `MAX` value for each Group.
`COUNTIFS`: Returns the count of each Group.
`SUMPRODUCT`: Returns the addition of the division of each Group's `Max` value by it's `Count`.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

**Dynamic Array Functions**

**IF** you have access to the new dynamic array functions, @MichaelWycisk has a much simpler solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/59306217/1473412)

Sadly I do not.

---

**SUMPRODUCT**

I have managed to do it using `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
    (
        $B$3:$B$14
        *
        ($B$3:$B$14=MAXIFS($B$3:$B$14,$A$3:$A$14,$A$3:$A$14))
    )
    /
    COUNTIFS($B$3:$B$14,MAXIFS($B$3:$B$14,$A$3:$A$14,$A$3:$A$14),$A$3:$A$14,$A$3:$A$14)
)
```

[image]

The way it works is to multiply the values by whether or not it is the max value for the group.
Then it divides that by the count of values which are the max value for the group.

Comment: I should have thought of that, not had my morning caffeine yet.

Answer (score 4):

I understand you do not want to have array formulas. But if you would be fine with the new dynamic arrays (no CONTROL + SHIFT + ENTER needed), you might use this formula:

```
=SUM(MAXIFS(B3:B14,A3:A14,UNIQUE(A3:A14)))
```

Of course, this will only work if the `UNIQUE` function is already available to you.

Comment: Thanks... turns out they aren't available to me but i'm not sure why not. Should they be available in the latest version of 365? Or are they "Office Insiders" only still?

Comment: @Gravitate No, I am not an Office Insider and I have them on two machines. I was recently told here on SO that it depends on your update circle. Sorry if the solution does not work for you.

Comment: No problem. Thank you for your help. That will certainly make things easier when I do get the update :)

Comment: @Gravitate, go to your account page in Excel.  It will tell you the schedule of updates.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks, but unfortunately it's not just my updates I have to worry about. The sheet is to be used by a number of people... many of whom are months behind with updates.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=SUM(MAXIFS(B3:B14,A3:A14,{1,2,3,4}))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but that would require me to know all the group names in advance.

Comment: With the new unique function that returns an array of unique values it can be done without knowing in advance the values: `=SUM(MAXIFS(B3:B14,A3:A14,UNIQUE(A3:A14)))`

Comment: Yes... if you check above, that was @MichaelWycisk's answer, which he posted 10 days before you posted yours: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59306217/1473412